# Running Commands from C#

Tags: c#

Worst topic but can't really say much more.

Thing is, i am trying to run a certain command from cmd, if i do this normally in windows, it's flawless, in C# it doesn't work, even though it's the exact same string.

Here is how i do it:

```
        Process cwebp = new Process();
        cwebp.StartInfo.FileName=("cmd.exe");
       cwebp.StartInfo.Arguments = Settings.EncoderSettings[0];
       cwebp.Start();
```

And well arguments is pretty much anything, for example:

opusenc --bitrate 100 input.wav output.opus

Is there any fundamental issue here?
Been searching a lot and can't find any information, everything says (use Arguments), and i do, and it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work as expected" mean?

Comment: It doesn't work at all. CMD opens at the "build program" location. that's it, no execution, nothing.

Comment: Try executing the equivalent command and see what happens `cmd opusenc --bitrate 100 input.wav output.opus` vs `cmd /C opusenc --bitrate 100 input.wav output.opus`. For more info, see the [parameters for CMD.exe](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute a shell command you need to add the parameter /C (/K) on the arguments line

```
 Process cwebp = new Process();
 cwebp.StartInfo.FileName=("cmd.exe");
 cwebp.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C " + Settings.EncoderSettings[0];
 cwebp.Start();
```

Without it, the Process.Start method starts the cmd command processor, but, this one, exits immediately without processing the passed arguments.

Comment: This makes it do what i expect.
Is it possible to use the same process to run more commands after it's done with the first one, or do i have to remake it with startinfo arguments?

Comment: You can run a batch file with your commands or use the command concatenation separator `&&` Type cmd.exe /? to get the options available

Comment: Running a batch file is by far the easiest way; but it is also possible to make the cmd read its input from a stream you provide by redirecting its StdIn.

Comment: @Steve I see, thing is i am doing three processes, one of them combines 2 (uses stdin to another), i can run this in a Batch fine, but doing a batch for C#, i guess there is a way to change variables in it+

Comment: Batch files are simple text files, it is relatively easy to build them directly in your code and then execute them. Or you could check if the [command redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) works for you (the pipe operator for example)

Answer (score 5):

Additionally to Steve's answer, you can start your command directly, without using `cmd` in the first place:

```
Process.Start("opusenc", "--bitrate 100 input.wav output.opus");
```